# A reduction to the finite degree case

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I am stuck trying to understand a proof in *Asymptotic Differential Algebra and Model Theory of Transseries* by L. van den Dries, J. van der Hoeven and M. Aschenbrenner.

The result is the following:

Let $K$ be a field, let $A$ be a local ring of $K$ integrally closed in $K$ with maximal ideal $m_A$. Let $L / K$ be a normal extension, and let $B$ denote the integral closure of $A$ in $L$. If $q,q'$ are maximal ideals of $B$ such that $q \cap A = q' \cap A = m_A$, then there is $\sigma \in Aut(L |K)$ such that $\sigma(q) = q'$.

I understand the proof, except the start, when they write that one can assume $[L : K]$ is finite. Does anyone see how this case yields the general one?

Answer (score 2):

I think we could argue as follows: suppose you prove the claim for some *finite* normal subextension $\;L'/K\;$ of $\;L/K\;$ . Now, take an element $\;\sigma\in\text{Aut}\,\left(L'/K\right)\;$ fulfilling $\;\sigma q= q'\;$ .

Since $\;L/K\;$ is algebraic (this is a "hidden" assumption, I think, since "normal extension", as far as I know, is only applied to algebraic extensions), we can extend $\;\sigma\;$ to a $\;K\,-$  embedding $\;\Sigma:L\to \overline K\;$ , where the last field is some (the) algebraic closure of $\;K\;$ which of course contains $\;L\;$, too, and since $\;L/K\;$ is *normal* then in fact this embedding is *an automorphism* of $\;L/K\;$ , so in fact $\;\Sigma\in\text{Aut}/\left(L/K\right)\;$ , and of course $\;\Sigma\uparrow_{L'}=\sigma\;$, so still $\;\Sigma q=q'\;$.

Comment: This seems to be the idea, but so far this only proves the result for $q,q'$ maximal ideals in the integral closure of $A$ in $L'$, not in $L$.

Comment: @nombre But $\;L'\subset L\;$ , of course. I thought this was clear but I added some words to my answer now.

Comment: Yes but the integral closure $B'$ of $A$ in $L'$ is a priori strictly contained in its integral closure $B$ in $L$ so maximal ideals in $B'$ need not be maximal ideals in $B$.

Comment: @nombre Well, user26857 got ahead of what I was going to write now. If we can't assume as shown in my answer, then the reduction you mention those authors assume in their proof may be way messier to get and we may have to go to infinite Galois theory, profinite groups and all that. Now, I honestly doubt that's the case as then the authors, I think, would have mentioned this, so either there's some info missing (look at the beginning of the chapter, perhaps), or else there's a slick trick I can't see to overcome this difficulty...or else the authors just threw that on your way to deal with it.

Comment: I don't think they left something that requires infinite Galois theory without mentionning it. They tend to skip some non trivial results at times but at least they are synthetic results that you could guess and look for. What is more probable is that I have misunderstood the reduction. The proposition of the book regards valued fields; perhaps it is intended that the reduction occurs at this level and then the statement with ideals in proved is the finite case.